# TSQL Round up decimal number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I have this number 0.581183781439, I need to round the number 0.582

I was trying with

```
SELECT ROUND (0.581183781439, 3)
-------------------------------
0.581000000000
```

Is it useful ROUND function for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you need this?

```
SELECT ROUND(0.581183781439, 3,1) + .001
```

but correct rounding is `0.581`.

Comment: Well, that's a great idea.

Comment: Yeah, I always need rounding up in this case.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the OP really wants a value of 0.581000000000 to round up to 0.582.

Answer (score 11):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (Col NUMERIC(38,12));

INSERT  @Test (Col)
SELECT 0.581183781439 
UNION ALL
SELECT 0.5815
UNION ALL
SELECT 0.581883781439
UNION ALL
SELECT -0.581883781439;

SELECT Col AS [Col],
    ROUND(Col, 3) AS StandardRounding_3decimals,
    ROUND(Col, 3, 1) AS Truncation_3decimals,
    FLOOR(Col*1000)/1000 AS RoundDown_3decimals,
    CEILING(Col*1000)/1000  AS RoundUp_3decimals 
FROM @Test;
```

Results:

```
Col             StandardRounding_3decimals Truncation_3decimals RoundDown_3decimals RoundUp_3decimals
--------------- -------------------------- -------------------- ------------------- -----------------
0.581183781439  0.581000000000             0.581000000000       0.581000            0.582000
0.581500000000  0.582000000000             0.581000000000       0.581000            0.582000
0.581883781439  0.582000000000             0.581000000000       0.581000            0.582000
-0.581883781439 -0.582000000000            -0.581000000000      -0.582000           -0.581000
```

Answer (score 5):

We can write a T-SQL function to round up for an arbitrary number of decimal places.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RoundUp (@value float, @places int) RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT CEILING(@value * POWER(10, @places)) / POWER(10, @places)
END
GO

SELECT Result = dbo.RoundUp(0.581183781439, 3)
```

> ### Result
>
> 0.582

Answer (score 0):

Adding a half value and using normal round will get the correct result.

```
SELECT ROUND (0.581183781439 + .0005, 3)
```

Bonus: Subtract the half value instead, and it will round down.

*EDIT*: Actually, this has the same flaw as an answer above when the value is zeros after the 3rd decimal.