# Is there a equivalent roundup of excel to sql query?

Tags: sql, excel

I what to know if there is equivalent function of roundup of excel in sql query?

Especially for `roundup(value,2)`

in SQL using round:

```
select  cast(ROUND(350.00/24,2) as decimal(18,2))

result = 14.58
```

in Excel using roundup

```
result = 14.59
```

How can I achieve excel's roundup result in sql?

Comment: So is your question about why the outputs are different?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yeh and i want to achieve same ouput as excel's roundup

Answer (score 1):

There is:

select round(12.4343423, 2)

first = number
second = decimal places

---

OR

SELECT CEILING(111.45) becomes 112

Answer (score 1):

You can do excel like round-up by this query:

```
SELECT CEILING( (350.00/24) * 100 ) / 100
```

> **Result** 
>  14.59

You can also write a TSQL function to roundup like excel( as [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63264/anthony-faull), [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991801/554969) to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059164/tsql-round-up-decimal-number)) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION RoundUp(@value float, @places int) 
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT CEILING(@value * POWER(10, @places)) / POWER(10, @places)
END
GO
```

And you can call this function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.RoundUp(350.00/24, 2)
```

> **Result** 
>  14.59