# SQL automatically rounding off values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two table. First table(Table1) use to get the records and second table(Table2) used to insert first table record into it. But I am little bit confused after getting result.

In table 1 and table 2 column "Amount" have same data type i.e nvarchar(max)

Table1

```
Id   Amount
1    Null
2    -89437.43
2    -533.43
3    22403.88
```

If I run this query

```
Insert into Table2(Amount)
Select Amount from Table1
```

Then get result like this, I don't know why values are automatically rounded off

```
Table2

Id   Amount
1    Null
2    -89437.4
2    -533.43
3    22403.9
```

Comment: what are the data types of the columns in both tables?

Comment: Have you tried using DECIMAL as type?

Comment: @Greg `nvarchar(max)` it's in the question. Not sure why numeric values are being stored in an `nvarchar` field though?

Comment: @Greg Its nvarchar(max). Already mentioned in question

Comment: @Tanner Because requirement is also want to null and blank value.

Comment: @Subhash sorry, my bad, but why numbers stored as nvarchar(max)? It's inefficient for storage, and you can't perform mathematical functions on the data.

Comment: @Subhash you can still have nullable of int.

Comment: What @Greg said... your issue will be with `blank` which will either have to be 0 or null. numeric fields won't accept blank

Comment: @Greg but what about if I want to insert blank value

Comment: @Subhash I don't know why you would want blank value as well as null value, as well as zero... I would consider redesign...perhaps a separate flag...

Comment: @Greg It's client requirement. Is there were any way to do this.

Comment: For a numeric field why is blank different to null in your case?

Comment: Are you sure Amount is nvarchar(max) in both tables?  If you just Select Amount from Table1 what do you get?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server *will* round float values when converting back and to from string types.
And then you have the fun bits of empty string being 0, as well other strange effects

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('' AS float) AS nvarchar(MAX))
SELECT CAST(CAST('0.E0' AS float) AS nvarchar(MAX))
```

Use decimal.

If you need to store "blank" (how does this differ from NULL?) use a separate bit column to allow that extra value

Comment: My Amount column stored only 7 digits like 1234567 is 123456. How to stored more than 7 digits using select query.

Comment: Don't truncate it. You will still have rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/automatic-decimal-rounding-issue) is good explanation about your question.

Eigher you explicitly give float or decimal or numeric(xx,x) (x means numeric value)

Then it will convert as the data, other wise it round off the last value.

```
Insert into Table2(Amount)
Select cast(Amount as numeric(18,2) --or  , cast (Amount as float)
from Table1
```

Check this link:-
[TSQL Round up decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059164/tsql-round-up-decimal-number)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was doing the conversion to the correct data type but had decimal(18,0) for the column in the table. So make sure the decimal places are represented properly for the column decimal(18,2).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's your query tool that's truncating to 8 characters.

Check the actual fields lengths to see if the problem is really in the database:

```
SELECT LEN(Amount)
FROM Table2
WHERE Amount LIKE '%-89437.%'
```

Comment: But one is truncated to 7.  I am pretty sure we and not getting a full accurate story from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Unreproducible.   Running this script on SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ([Amount] nvarchar(max) NULL);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE ([Amount] nvarchar(max) NULL);

INSERT INTO @T1 ([Amount])
VALUES (NULL),('-89437.43'),('-533.43'),('22403.88');

Insert into @T2(Amount)
Select Amount from @T1;

SELECT * FROM @T2;
```

Produces this result:

```
Amount
NULL
-89437.43
-533.43
22403.88
```

The problem you describe does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the problem:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ([Amount123456789] money NULL);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE ([Amount123456789] nvarchar(max) NULL);

INSERT INTO @T1 ([Amount123456789])
VALUES (NULL),('-89437.43123'),('-533.43456'),('22403.88789'),(22403.88789);

Insert into @T2(Amount123456789)
Select Amount123456789 from @T1;

SELECT * FROM @T1;
SELECT * FROM @T2;
```